# How to set new value for data of parental component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<template>
<div>
    <input @keypress.enter="setLocation" class="search" type="text" placeholder="find a city" v-model="newCity">
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    props:['city'],
    data(){
        return{
            newCity:""
        }
    },
    methods:{
        setLocation(event){
            this.city = newCity
            this.$emit('newLocation', this.city)
        }
    }
}
```

when I am trying to submit it it says newCity is not defined.
Did they change v-model property in Vue.js update?

Comment: You forgot to put `this`: `this.newCity` and why do you change `city` prop?

Comment: to change the data of parental element

Comment: Parent needs to be changed through events. You should not generally change props

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: in parent template: `<your-component @new-location="methodToSetIt">` and you can access city in first argument `methodToSetIt`

Comment: instead of @keypress.enter="setLocation" you can use watch propery for newCity data

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько please dont use comments to answer the question, makes it hard to see if the solution is provided.